# Creating an object of one class in another class?

Tags: java, constructor

I have two classses and I wonder why I always get an error when I try to create an object of class "Knoten" in a method of class "Graph".

Class Graph

```
public class Graph
{

    static Knoten[] knotenliste;


        public void punktHinzufuegen(int x, int y){
            for(int i=0;i<Gui.zaehler;i++){
                knotenliste[i]=new Knoten(x,y);

            }
        }
    }
```

Class Knoten:

```
public class Knoten{

int xPos;
int yPos;

    public Knoten(int x,int y){
       xPos=x;
       yPos=y;
    }


}
```

Every time I call method punktHinzufuegen I get an error. Thanks for helping..

Comment: Maybe you could provide the error message, then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: you must be getting a NullPointer Exception since you have not initialize the knotenliste static state. Please initialize this and that might get your issue resolved. if not ping the issue you are getting after this.

Comment: you should initialize size of knotenliste array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized your array and I think you are getting `NullPointerException` while adding elements. You need to initialize it before adding elements to it

```
static Knoten[] knotenliste = new Knoten[<SOME_INT_VALUE>];
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Whats your btc address?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a very easy problem to solve, so I'll give a short explanation/solution.

What your current problem is, is that you are not defining your **knotenliste**.
You should define it as the following field:

```
private static Knoten[] knotenliste = new Knoten[Gui.zaehler];
```

I would suggest that you do not use a *static* value but start working with either a fixed **ArrayList** (in order to index your graph points) or a **Queue**. Both of those can be found on the Java documentation if you're intested in reading about them.
What I would have done is the following:

```
public class Graph {

    private final ArrayList<Knoten> knotenliste = new ArrayList<>(Gui.zaehler);

    public void punktHinzufuegen(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Gui.zaehler; i++) {
            // Keep in mind that the List#add(int index, E element) will 
            // shift all the elements previously in the array to the right.
            knotenliste.add(i, new Knoten(x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

With this you do not only stop abusing the static keyword, but you also have a more flexible Collection to save your Knoten in.

Comment: Note that `List#add(int index,E object)` **inserts** the value and **shifts** all values on the 'right' side of the list by one place. The original method from OP overwrites the data stored in the array. So your List approach does not feature the same funtionality as the orignal method. Otherwise a clean answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. You're absolutely right and I edited my answer with the right description. Possibly best way for him to approach this is by using the `List#set(int index, E element)`, but as he already had a problem with the static keyword and the Array Object, it felt better to give this as an solution. Otherwise, myself, depending on the situation (if the Graph sould be randomly accessable), I would have used a `Queue` or `ArrayDequeu`.